# Any quick way to restore or reset closures in clojure to initial state?

Tags: clojure, closures, reset

Is there any quick way to restore or reset closures to their initial states? E.g. in below function, how can I reset values of stat1 and stat2 associated with myClosureFn back to 1?

The context of this question: I use below structure in different functions, and one function may "mess up" values associated with the closure. So I'd need to reset/restore it to initial states in order to pass it again into another function.

```
(def myClosureFn 
  (let [stat1 (atom 1)
        stat2 (atom 1)
        ;..stat3 stat4 ...
        ]
    (fn [m]
      (swap! stat1 inc)
      (reset!   stat2 (* 2 m))
      [@stat1  @stat2])))

(myClosureFn 1) ;--> [2 2] 
(myClosureFn 2) ;--> [3 4]
(myClosureFn 2) ;--> [4 4]
(myClosureFn 3) ;--> [5 6]
;...
; how to get [ 1 1 ] back to myClosureFn ?
```

Comment: Why `(def myClosureFn (let ... (fn [m] ... )))` instead of `(let ... (defn myClosureFn [m] ...))`?

Comment: Why do you need to share state between different invocations of this function? In general the Clojure philosophy is that shared, mutable state is something to be avoided when possible.

Comment: @ToBeReplaced Because the code needs to access this part as a function multiple times. Basically I have multiple closure functions like above serving as txt line parser, and calculation function may call parser functions multiple times to grab data. To keep efficiency I want to open and close the file just once, and I need to be able to add new functions and new parsers.

A related question is here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15563919/is-clojures-read-file-structure-i-e-with-open-and-clojure-java-io-reader-eff)

Comment: @Alex Thanks a lot! I got this question during the process of re-factoring my ugly code. Input is bunch of different type of data in txt file that I used a lot of regexp to filter out, while calculation part are different type of functions. In order to speed up, I refactored parser to closure function like above such that info on each line of txt file can be processed by multiple parser functions. (it used to be that each calculation part will read the whole file again!) During this process a closure parser function may need to be reset when a calculation is taking another txt file as input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than explicitly having to re-set the state associated with your function, consider using a higher-order function:

```
(defn myClosureFn []
  (let [stat1 (atom 1)
        stat2 (atom 1)
        ;..stat3 stat4 ...
        ]
    (fn [m]
      (swap! stat1 inc)
      (reset!   stat2 (* 2 m))
      [@stat1  @stat2])))
```

So, to get fresh state, you just call `myClosureFn` which returns a function with clean counters. For example:

```
> (def f1 (myClosureFn))
> (def f2 (myClosureFn))
> (f1 1) ;--> [2 2]
> (f1 2) ;--> [3 4]
> (f2 1) ;--> [2 2]
> (f1 3) ;--> [4 6]
```

Instead of having global state, each function carries around its own state with it. You can even create and use two such functions at the same time and they won't interfere with each other.

Answer (score 2):

You can make `myClosureFn` to act like a reset function when no argument is passed

```
(def myClosureFn 
  (let [stat1 (atom 1)
        stat2 (atom 1)
        ;..stat3 stat4 ...
        ]
    (fn [& [m]]
      (if m
        (do
          (swap! stat1 inc)
          (reset!   stat2 (* 2 m))
          [@stat1  @stat2])
        (do
          (reset! stat1 1)
          (reset! stat2 1))))))


(myClosureFn 1) ;--> [2 2] 
(myClosureFn 2) ;--> [3 4]
(myClosureFn) ;reset to 1 1
```

OR if you are using REPL, then just re-evaluate the `myClosureFn` form again in REPL.

Comment: Thanks Ankur a lot! After I play around with my code a bit, I find Alex's style is cleaner, but your answer here is very helpful too